# Mininet static host mac addresses are not set from script

Tags: mininet, sdn, pox

I’m attempting to statically set mac addresses for my hosts in my mininet script.

below is the script being ran

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.topo import Topo

class CustomTopo(Topo):
    def build(self):
     #statically assigned host mac addresses
     h1 = self.addHost('h1', mac='D3:13:1C:1B:76:A0')
     h2 = self.addHost('h2', mac='8B:94:91:62:F1:65')
     s1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
     s2 = self.addSwitch('s2')

     self.addLink(s1,s2)

     self.addLink(h1,s1)
     self.addLink(h2,s2)

topo = CustomTopo()
topos = { 'customtopo': ( lambda: CustomTopo() ) }
```

But upon verifying the configuration on the host h2 for example, the statically assigned mac 8B:94:91:62:F1:65 is not present for eth0.

```
sudo mn -c
sudo mn --custom script.py --topo customtopo --controller=remote

mininet> h2 ifconfig
h2-eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::f4da:8dff:fe8d:c696  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:da:8d:8d:c6:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 40  bytes 5598 (5.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 676 (676.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

from the [mininet mailing list](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2015-February/005738.html) this should be the proper way to set the mac address.

```
net = Mininet()
h1 = net.addHost( 'h1', ip='10.9/24', mac='00:00:00:00:00:09' )
h2 = net.addHost( 'h2' )
s1 = net.addSwitch( 's1' )
c0 = net.addController( 'c0' )
net.addLink( h1, s1 )
net.addLink( h2, s1 )
net.start()
print h1.cmd( 'ifconfig' )
CLI( net )
net.stop()
```

...
h1-eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:09
inet addr:10.0.0.9  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
...

Answer (score 0):

Your MAC addresses are set as Broadcast addresses, which is invalid on host devices. Fix it by changing them to Unicast addresses.

For example: `h2 = self.addHost('h2', mac='8A:94:91:62:F1:65')`